# how to prevent the implicit conversion of double value to integer

Tags: c++

I am taking user input as integer and selecting the function to run depending on it. However, When I enter 1.3 as car_choice, it takes the 1 as input, runs the program for the first case. How can I prevent this? I am using C++.

```
int car_choice;
std::cout << "Please enter the vehicle types for calculations\n";
do
{

    std::cout << "Please enter your choice in number:\n";
    std::cout << "1) VW Car\n";
    std::cout << "2) Audi Car\n";
    std::cout << "3) Toyota Car\n";
    std::cout << "4) Do not want to enter any number and to stop\n";
    std::cin >> car_choice;
} while (car_choice != 1 && car_choice != 2 &&
    car_choice != 3 && car_choice != 4);
```

Comment: This code is at a place where I have to imagine the instructor has no requirements for input validation.

Comment: *"However, When I enter 12.3 as car_choice, it takes the 1 as input"* - This shouldn't happen with the code you posted (unless you meant `1.23` as opposed to `12.3`).

Comment: One way to prevent it is to read the user input as a string, check the content of every character in the string, and discard the string if it contains characters like a decimal point.     There is no way to change the behaviour when a decimal point is present if you insist on using `std::cin >> car_choice` - given input of `1.23` it will read the `1` as an integral value, leave the `.23` in the stream buffer.

Comment: @0x5453: Thanks, it was mistyped. it should 1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't doing any input validation: you ask `std::cin`, an input data stream, for an integer. `std::cin` then builds an integer from that stream, consuming numerical digits (and maybe a `-` too) until either the stream ends, or until the next byte of data wouldn't be valid for an integer.

Perhaps you should read in your input as a string of text; from there, you could then determine if the input is valid before converting it to an `int`.

It looks like [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) could help. Consider this example, based off of one from within the link:

```
int car_choice = -1;
std::string car_choice_string;
std::cin >> car_choice_string;
if (auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(car_choice_string.data(),
                                   car_choice_string.data() + car_choice_string.size(),
                                   car_choice);
    ec == std::errc())
{
    // User input was an integer, car_choice now contains that value
} else {
    // Input was invalid, car_choice will keep its value of -1.
}
```

**Edit:**

In your specific case of wanting a single digit, the following could also work:

```
int car_choice = -1;
std::string car_choice_string;
std::cin >> car_choice_string;

if (car_choice_str.size() == 1 && std::isdigit(car_choice_str.front()))
    car_choice = car_choice_str.front() - '0';
```

Comment: I won't say that it is wrong, but why does it have to be so enormously difficult?

Comment: Because `std::cin` wasn't tailored for interactive user input, `std::cin` is simply a stream of data (`std::istream`). Why aren't C++ streams strict about matching input? That's a good question; perhaps they've gained more flexibility/utility by being more relaxed about matching input to data types.

Comment: @clyne: I tried the code that you mentioned for the single-digit user acceptance and it worked. thanks.

Comment: @Surendra: Glad to help. If my answer satisfies your question, would you mind accepting it (with the check mark)? That helps others see that you found a good solution.

Answer (score -2):

It's not really clear to me why you want to use a float number as input to relate it to an object, but it doesn't sound like a very 'neat' solution.

Since you want to select an object out of a list of available options, I would suggest that you use enumeration instead of having a float number as input. Not sure about the C++ syntax, but just to give you an example, it would be something like that:

```
enum car {
   VW,
   AUDI,
   TOYOTA,
   NO_CAR_SELECTED
}
```

If you haven't used enum before, have a look here to get a better understanding: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum

If you still want to use a numerical input to assign it to car, then try using integer instead of float number as input.

Comment: The asker only wants integer input. Their issue is with handling invalid input; for example, when the user enters a decimal number instead. Using an enum will not affect the asker's problem.

Comment: No one wants to use a `float` to select a car. The OP is trying to read an `int`, but if they type invalid input like `12.3` (which is not an integer), the built in parsing  "makes it work" by apparently reading just `1` (well, when I test it I get `12`, but same difference) instead of raising some kind of error, which is what the OP wants (so they can say "please input a choice" or whatever).

Comment: enum only takes an integer.  If a user tries to enter decimal values/double, this runs into a problem. I am looking for something that can take care of double value. Thanks for the response @leonidasarch.